# Install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS inside Windows 8

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

When I go and select a way how to install Ubuntu on my computer, there is an option: *Install Ubuntu inside Windows 8*. I click that and it says *Restart to continue*. I press restart and then the computer reboots into Windows. Nothing else happens.  Here is what it says:

[image]

What to do?

Comment: That option installs WUBI, which is no longer supported, should not be used, and is thoroughly incompatible with newer UEFI systems. One of the minor hazards of using an older release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

That option installs WUBI, which is **no longer supported**, should not be used, and is thoroughly incompatible with newer UEFI systems.

If you simply wish to try Ubuntu without risk to your existing Windows 8 install, use the 'Try Ubuntu' option instead of launching the installer. This will launch an Ubuntu session entirely in RAM; nothing will be installed to your hard drive.

If you have tried Ubuntu, and decided you want it, and if your hardware will support it, the safest way is to install a Virtual Machine application in Windows, and install an Ubuntu VM guest. Note that the VM depends upon the Windows host - a broken or compromised Windows install will break Ubuntu, too.

Alternately, you can modify your Windows install, shrink your partitions, and install Ubuntu and Windows side-by-side. Repartitioning a Windows system is risky - you might break your Windows install and lose your data. Make sure your data is fully backed up before starting. If you wish to repair or reinstall Windows someday, make sure you have your Windows Product Key written down, else you must purchase a new key from Microsoft.

Alternately, you can delete your entire Windows install and replace it with an Ubuntu system. This process will delete all data and applications. Windows applications do not work on Ubuntu at all, and --depending upon your skill level-- there may be a bit of culture shock. Before transitionin OS, change to multi-platform applications(like LibreOffice instead of MSOffice) to make the transition easier.